# setting up relationships with a table for the links

Tags: neo4j

I'm very new to Neo4j:

I'm moving MySQL data to visualise and anaylise the data but I can't set up the relationships.

So far my build script looks like this:

```
// Create Players
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:player.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Player {   playerID: row.id, name: row.Name });
CREATE INDEX ON :Player(name);
CREATE INDEX ON :Player(playerID);

// Create Team
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:team.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Team {   teamID: row.id });
CREATE INDEX ON :Team(teamID);

// Create PlayerLinks
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:playerlinks.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Links {   linkID: row.id, fromPlayerID: row.fromPlayerID, toPlayerId: row.toPlayerId, teamID: row.teamID, years: row.years });


MATCH   (p:Player),(t:Team), (l:Links)
WHERE   l.fromPlayerID = p.playerID
AND     l.toPlayerId = p.playerID
AND     l.teamID = t.teamID
CREATE
```

The table `playerlinks` contains the relationships I'd like to create

Here's a diagram of what I'm aiming to achieve:
[image: Players]

Comment: For one, you don't need to create an index for every node you add. Once a schema index is created, it will apply to any node added with that label. So if your indexes are already in place, you can remove them from your script completely. Though I would recommend using a unique constraint instead of an index when it comes to your ID fields. Also, you haven't specified what's going wrong with your script. Can you paste in the errors you are getting trying to run it, or better describe the problems you're running into?

Comment: Maybe add a representative diagram of how the resulting structure should look?

Comment: Could you also explain a little bit about your :Links? I can understanding linking a player to a team, but you are also specifying on the same row a link from one player to another, without mention of the nature of this relationship. What is this player to player link meant to represent?

Comment: I've added a diagram, with the links holding the years played together and for what team

Comment: so each row in the links table joins two players and holds some information

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're almost there, actually.

As mentioned in my comments on the question itself, you'll want to drop index creation from your scripts (those should be applied only once before you do your import, and you should consider using unique constraints for ID fields).

As for your :Links nodes, is your plan to only use them to create relationships, or do you plan on keeping them around afterwards?

The approach for keeping :Links around as intermediate nodes with relationships from your :Links nodes to other elements of your graph, might look like this:

```
MATCH   (l:Links)
WITH l
MATCH   (p1:Player), (p2:Player), (t:Team)
WHERE   l.fromPlayerID = p1.playerID
AND     l.toPlayerId = p2.playerID
AND     l.teamID = t.teamID
MERGE  (l)-[:Teammate]->(p1)
MERGE  (l)-[:Teammate]->(p2)
MERGE  (l)-[:PlayedOn]->(t)
```

That connects your :Links node to the players who are teammates, to the :Team they played on, and your :Links node holds the years they played together. At that point you can remove the linkID, toPlayerID, fromPlayerID, and teamID properties from the node, since in a graph db relationships tend to replace foreign keys when translating from a relational db, and since you likely won't be looking up :Links nodes by ID.

Alternately (and according to your desired diagram) you can use the info on the :Links nodes to create relationships between :Players directly. You can set attributes on the relationships for the number of years played together and the ID (or name) of the team they played on. Keep in mind that the relationship itself will not be able to point at the :Team node where the players played together, though you should be able to use that info to create :PlayedOn relationships from the :Players to the :Team in question.

That kind of modeling might look like this:

```
MATCH   (l:Links)
WITH l
MATCH   (p1:Player), (p2:Player), (t:Team)
WHERE   l.fromPlayerID = p1.playerID
AND     l.toPlayerId = p2.playerID
AND     l.teamID = t.teamID
MERGE  (p1)-[:Teammate{years: l.years, team: t.teamID}]->(p2)
MERGE  (p1)-[:PlayedOn]->(t)
MERGE  (p2)-[:PlayedOn]->(t)
```

Keep in mind the MERGING of the :Teammate relationship may be slow. If you only plan on running this only once, you can use CREATE instead of MERGE.

Comment: thanks for the help, I've run the 2nd query as it looks like what I'm aiming for.
However when I run it, there aren't any errors but the relationships aren't created ( as in I can't see them in the browser )

Comment: You won't see them as a result of the creation query, but you should see feedback that the relationships are created. To query for players who are teammates, try this query: `MATCH (p1:Player)-[r:Teammate]->(p2:Player) RETURN p1, r, p2`

Comment: no feedback as such and that query returns no results, I can see the nodes have all been created. 
However, the relationship creation finishes in 163ms and the relationship types remains empty

Comment: I can confirm that the nodes exist in the graph 
I'm using: 
MATCH (n:Links)
RETURN n
LIMIT 25;

For each label and it's giving me what I expect

Comment: So you're not getting any relationships created? You may want to double-check whether `ID` is upper or lowercase or mixed where it's used (both on :Links and :Player nodes), as your original query has :Links with `toPlayerId`, but it's uppercase on `fromPlayerID`. My query preserves the case in your query, but if that was just a typo when you pasted it, that would explain why relationships aren't being created.